# python opencv shape detection

Tags: python, opencv

For a school project I'm trying to recognize a hexagon shape in a video capture using python and opencv. The problem is that when I use this code, it never finds a hexagon. I haven't found a reason why it isn't working so I hope someone can help me.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

stop_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    lower = np.array([0,0,0])
    upper = np.array([20,20,20])
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
    contours, h = cv2.findContours(mask, 1, 2)
    contours.sort(key = len)

    for contour in contours[-3:]:
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,0.1*cv2.arcLength(contour,True),True)
        if len(approx) == 6:
            print "hexagon"

    cv2.imshow('image', mask)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks in advance

Edit:
To be a little more specific. I've tried mulitple different hexagons but when I print the len(approx) it is never higher then 4. Is this a fault in my object or is it that I have an error in finding the contours i don't know about?

Comment: What have you done in the way of actually debugging your program, instead of saying "I haven't found a reason why it isn't working so I hope someone can help me?" Please have a *specific* question, not "please debug this..."

Comment: I'm sorry for not being specific enough. What I have done to debug the code is holding different hexagon shapes in front of the camera, while the program printed the len(approx) but it never showed a number higher then 4. I this problem this way because of my objects (a hexon shaped image on paper) or is it i fault in finding the contours?

Comment: Can you attach the sample input?

Comment: @ZdaR The sample is just a simple black hexagon drawn on a piece of paper

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your program is simplifying the contour beyond what you would like. So *approxPolyDP* is further simplifying your hexagon to a square or triangle. This would also explain why *len(approx)* never returns a value greater than 4. Try changing the value of *epsilon* that you pass to *approxPolyDP*. These are the changes I suggest:

1. Try a range of values for epsilon in *approxPolyDP*. Change the multiplication factor in `0.1*cv2.arcLength(contour,True)` from 0.01 to 0.1
2. Use *drawContours* to actually display the *approx* curve. This will help you choose the best multiplication factor

Another approach is using the convex hull of the hexagon rather than the contour and then apply the *approxPolyDP* function. Ideally, if your image is sharp enough just checking the number of points in the convex hull should be enough to tell you whether the shape is a hexagon or not. Simplifying the hull further should help you be more robust to noisy images. But again choosing the correct multiplication factor will be important.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,0.03*cv2.arcLength(contour,True),True)
```

you will get the desired result.